# Change position and sum into an new series of number

Tags: r

I use a simple and replicable example:

I have a function `f`

```
f <- function(x){
    e <- seq(1, x, by = (sqrt(x)))
    e    
}
```

For example:

```
> f(1)
[1] 1
> f(2)
[1] 1
> f(3)
[1] 1.000000 2.732051
> f(4)
[1] 1 3
> f(5)
[1] 1.000000 3.236068
```

I would like to create a series `N` that sum each output from for `f(1)` to `f(4)` in the following way (changing position +1 each time):

```
# f(1)= 1
# f(2)=   1
# f(3)=      1.000000  2.732051
# f(4)=                1         3
# f(4)=                          1.000000   3.236068

#  N = 1  1  1.000000  3.732051  4.000000   3.236068  etc...
```

As you see the length of each one can be different.

Any help?

Comment: Do you want the output to be a matrix? Is this a cumulative sum?

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this with `sapply`:

```
sapply(1:4, function(i) sum(f(i)))
```

`sapply` takes the vector 1:4 as an input. I then created a throw away "lambda" function that takes each element of 1:4, and sums the output of your `f` function.

If you would like to sum this output, you could wrap it in `sum` or `cumsum` for a cumulative summation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `*apply` to apply your function to the series, but to sum it, you'll need to insert zeros before and after. You can use `rowSums` to take the actual sum:

```
N1 <- sapply(1:5, 
            function(x){
                c(rep(0, x - 1),    # insert zeros before
                  f(x), 
                  rep(0, 6 - (length(f(x)) + x - 1)))    # insert zeros after
            })
N1
#      [,1] [,2]     [,3] [,4]     [,5]
# [1,]    1    0 0.000000    0 0.000000
# [2,]    0    1 0.000000    0 0.000000
# [3,]    0    0 1.000000    0 0.000000
# [4,]    0    0 2.732051    1 0.000000
# [5,]    0    0 0.000000    3 1.000000
# [6,]    0    0 0.000000    0 3.236068

N2 <- rowSums(N1)
N2
# [1] 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 3.732051 4.000000 3.236068
```